# Add style to body on one of SPA pages

Tags: javascript, css, react-router

A have SPA (react-router@5) and it always loads all styles of all pages(for now I dont want to implement components hot loading).

I need to add a style to body but only for one of my pages. I see an obvious solution to add at necessary component

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style['overflow-y'] = 'hidden'
```

but i would like to use css for that. Is there any other solutions?

Comment: You can add class with a given style to the component's wrapper element

Comment: how would it help to add style to body?

Comment: You don't need to add any styles to the body. Create a wrapper div with 100% height and width and attach the styles to it.

Comment: Also good, thanx